# tree selection for dojo

Tags: jquery, dojo, dynatree

jquery has a plugin [dynatree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) to achieve this. I want [this](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html) kind of effect with dojo. Is there a plugin or something for dojo which can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://thejekels.com/dojo/cbtree_AMD.html. I used this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people doing that kind of stuffs with dijit.Tree, but I do not think there is anything "built-in" though... I'd recommand you going to irc freenode #dojo and try contacting those guys to know how they proceeded